# Why aren't my e2e tests working in Rails/React app after updating to Rails 7

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, playwright

I have a rails/react app.

I upgraded from rails 6.1 to rails 7.0.4 recently.

I'm on React 18.
On Playwright - 1.17.1

For some reason after the Rails upgrade, all my e2e tests are failing and it's giving me so little to go on. Very odd because I didn't do any changes to the e2e tests, but of course it's all related in some way.

I boot up the test server locally to try and debug:

`./script/e2e/test-server.sh`

The test tries to run and it get stuck pretty much right away.

Once the server starts, I can go to http://0.0.0.0:5000/ and the default webpage loads.

But when I try to hit http://0.0.0.0:5000/login, that's when the login page never loads.

This is consistent with the actual line of code that the test is getting stuck on.

```
// some imports here

  readonly page: Page;

  constructor(page: Page) {
    this.page = page;
  }

// more code here

  async login(): Promise<void> {
    await this.page.goto(`${getRootURL()}/login`);
    if ((await this.page.url()) !== `${getRootURL()}/login`) {
      return; // Already logged in
    }

    await this.enterCredentials('e2e+collegeportal@raise.me', 'Student9');
  }
```

in particular, it's this line where the test gets stuck and never loads:

```
    await this.page.goto(`${getRootURL()}/login`);
```

Even if I change this URL to 'https://www.google.com' I get the same result, test browser opens up, and the test gets stuck here.

As far as errors go, I don't have a lot to go off of. There's one console error that may be related.

```
[module]:17 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' (at [module]:17:1)
    at ./node_modules/react-app-polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/es.array.map.js (vendor.js:34810:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:85:30)
    at eval (index.js:40:1)
    at ./node_modules/react-app-polyfill/node_modules/core-js/stable/index.js (vendor.js:37729:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:85:30)
    at eval (stable.js:12:1)
    at ./node_modules/react-app-polyfill/stable.js (vendor.js:37752:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:85:30)
    at eval (polyfill.ts:1:1)
    at ./frontend/src/utils/polyfill.ts (main.js:5213:1)
```

I tried updating react-app-polyfill to no avail. I tried updating playwright. No go.

The only other behavior I can describe is the terminal output from the test:

```
    page.click: Target closed
    =========================== logs ===========================
    waiting for selector "input[name="identifier"]"
    ============================================================
```

which I can tell it's saying that simply because the page is never loading.

If anyone has any thoughts whatsoever please let me know. Been stuck on this for days and don't have much else to go off of or try here.

Comment: there were a lot of changes in javascript bundling between rails 6 and 7. Javascript is hard to debug with system tests. Does the app work as expected in development mode?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yeah in development environment everything works perfectly fine. Just the tests are only failing pieces

Comment: Update to latest playwright, you seems to be on an old version anyways.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I updated my package.json file to use "version": "1.34.3". 

I then ran npm i  (from correct directory)
also had to do: npm install -D @playwright/test
package-lock.json looks good with the new version. BUT - same exact result as described above

Comment: you wrote "But when I try to hit http://0.0.0.0:5000/login, that's when the login page never loads" are you trying to visit the login page with a browser? Is this test env? What do you see in the log when you try to visit this page?

Comment: I have tried running the actual test locally by doing: 
./script/e2e/run-tests.sh -d -t '@test-name'
I also just hit that port in my browser to see if I could open the log in page. 5000 works fine but when I navigate to that login page it doesn't load. I was just noting I was seeing the same behavior both these methods when test server is running